# error: failed to push some refs to [remote] even though there is no conflict

Tags: git, github, push, git-merge

`git push origin <remote/branch>` gives me

```
To github.com:<remote/branch>
 ! [rejected]        feature/branch001-> feature/branch001 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<remote/branch>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

however when I do `git pull origin <remote/branch>`,  i get

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

After pushing to github, this merge commit shows no changed code at all - `+0 −0`

Why would git refuse to push though?

Comment: Because you were behind, simple as that. Git doesn't even verify whether a merge *could* easily be done because all of that has to be done on the client side, it simply refuses to push.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git pull` only. See, if that works.

Note: If you’ve named your origin already you should just be able to run `git pull` without naming the source. If you’re on a branch you may have to type `git pull origin branchname`.